# What happens with updates for purchased apps after the associated Google account is removed?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat, paid-apps

I've recently bought a new phone for my brother and I'd like to install my previously purchased apps on his device. I'm trying to understand: If I add my Google account (temporarily) on top of his account to install those purchased apps on his device, and then remove it (for privacy reasons), will those apps on his device get future updates via Play Store even without my account?

To add a bit of context, I'm trying to do this for Tasker and a bunch of automation apps I bought last week. Once I install Tasker on his phone and remove my Google account (which was used to purchase Tasker), will Tasker get future updates whenever the developer releases them, just like other apps on his device?

Also, Is there a way to transfer ownership of purchased apps from one Google account to another Google account?, For now, I'm using a newly created Google account to make and transfer purchases across all my devices (Unfortunately, this is not the case with the situation in question).

Any thoughts are appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: It's worth mentioning before someone could say: I'm from India and we don't have Google Play Family account yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All apps you've bought via your Google account are bound to that. Not only they cannot be updated without your account then (which is where they're bound to), but some of them will even stop working if you remove the account (those which use Google License Check to verify a valid license whenever you start them).

And no, there's no way of transferring ownership from one account to another. Though it would be technically possible, Google is not offering that.